# Format numbers into date in textbox during runtime in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, textbox

In my asp.net page I have a textbox where the user can put in a date.
For ease of use I would want it to automatically put a '-' when separating year with month and month with day without the user writing it him/herself.
So when the user writes: 20170911 it will be automatically formatted to 2017-09-11.

I have tried it with this JavaScript code:

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value.length == 4) {
    document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value + "-";
}
```

This will put an '-' after the 4th number but after pressing the 5th number. What I'm looking for however, is to be put after pressing the 4th number. Is there any way to do this in asp.net? I have seen it in multiple websites before so it technically should be possible, somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This kind of messing with user input is usually really annoying and extremely difficult to implement in an unobtrusive, intuitive way. Consider just letting the user type things themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the snippet below. As you type, the delimiter for date gets automatically inserted. Basically, you need to subscribe to `onkeyup` event that fires at end of every keystroke.

I have assumed that your date delimiter is the dash character i.e. `-`.

```js
var  emt = document.getElementById("txtDate");
emt.onkeyup =formatDate;

function formatDate(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                    return;
    }
    var dateValue = this.value;
    if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}$/) !== null) {
        this.value = dateValue + '-';
    } else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{2}$/) !== null) {
        this.value = dateValue + '-';
    } else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
          this.value = dateValue.substring(0, 4) + "-" + dateValue.substring(4);
    } else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{3}$/)) {
         this.value = dateValue.substring(0, 7) + "-" + dateValue.substring(7);
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDate" />
```

If you are using ASP.Net textbox then use code like below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DateBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="DateBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="formatDate(this)"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function formatDate(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                return;
            }
            var txtBox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
            var dateValue = txtBox.value;
            if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}$/) !== null) {
                txtBox.value = dateValue + '-';
            } else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{2}$/) !== null) {
                txtBox.value = dateValue + '-';
            }
            else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
                txtBox.value = dateValue.substring(0, 4) + "-" + dateValue.substring(4);
            }
            else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{3}$/)) {
                txtBox.value = dateValue.substring(0, 7) + "-" + dateValue.substring(7);
            }
         }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Another approach, which is similar to the first approach is as below, but it uses ASP.Net textbox.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DateBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="DateBox" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function pageLoad() {
                    var txtBox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
                    txtBox.onkeyup = formatDate;
                }
                function formatDate(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                    return;
                }
                var txtBox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
                var dateValue = txtBox.value;
                if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}$/) !== null) {
                    txtBox.value = dateValue + '-';
                } else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{2}$/) !== null) {
                    txtBox.value = dateValue + '-';
                }
                else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
                    txtBox.value = dateValue.substring(0, 4) + "-" + dateValue.substring(4);
                }
                else if (dateValue.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{3}$/)) {
                    txtBox.value = dateValue.substring(0, 7) + "-" + dateValue.substring(7);
                }
             }
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This seems to work for normal html textboxes, however I can't get it to work with the asp.net ones.

Comment: All you need to do is change the first line to `var emt =  document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");`.

Comment: Also add the first 2 lines to `function pageLoad() {   }`  event , i.e. to pageLoad event in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Also, I have posted another sample if you want to stick to ASP.Net text box.

Comment: This works quite badly. Type "2018" and it inserts a hyphen. If you really wanted 2017, you can't use delete to delete the 8 since every time you press delete, a new hyphen is inserted. I can use the cursor keys to move the insertion point back, and now can type whatever I want and no more hyphens will be inserted.

Comment: @RobG, You are right. I have included those cases also in the JavaScript and it should satisfy the requirement you highlighted. Thanks for bringing it up. I think some more cases will need to be added to make it completely satisfy your requirement.